# How to call this method in a background worker?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a beginner in C# and WPF and I am building this project in which I have to trigger when the mouse is moved. Under some conditions, I have to use it as a background worker. I want to call the mouse_Moved method in the background, but I don't know how to actually do that . Can anyone help me please? This is my code so far:

```
public MainWindow() 
{
   InitializeComponent();

   mouse = new MouseInput();
   mouse.MouseMoved += mouse_MouseMoved;

}
void mouse_MouseMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The code that I need
} 

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //where I want to call the mouse_Moved method
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method and call it from both:

```
void mouse_MouseMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoMouseMovedWork();
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DoMouseMovedWork();
}

private DoMouseMovedWork()
{
    //The code I need
}
```

Comment: Was it this easy? Lack of experience and a little brain.

Comment: @VaibhavTech We all started like you, and we are all yet to learn my friend. Mark this answer as accepted if you find it helpful (after 15 mins have passed on you question).